# Determine whether an integer can be constructed from other integers by applying bitwise AND and OR operations

Tags: boolean-algebra, binary

Given binary numbers $b_1, b_2, ... , b_m < 2^n$ as well as their complements $b'_1, b'_2, ..., b'_m$ (with leading $1$'s if necessary, such that $b_i + b'_i = 2^n - 1$), is it possible to quickly determine whether a number $k < 2^n$ can be constructed by repeatedly applying bitwise AND and OR?

For example, given `8, 10, 12` and `7, 5, 3` number `9` can be constructed as follows: `(3 & 5) | 8 = 9`. Note that the order of operations is always from left to right, like `(((a * b) * c) * d) * e ...`

If it's not possible, maybe there is a weaker test which tells whether in order to construct $k$ it would be necessary to use an XOR or XNOR, since they can't be simulated by using AND and OR sequentially?

Comment: What was tried ?

Comment: I tried determining it computationally. In the practical case that I'm trying to solve, I am limited to combining up to 8 numbers, so it's just about possible to do it by trying a depth-first search from both ends, where in the forward direction I am solving `a * b = x` and in the backward direction `x * a = b` with `*` being `&` or `|`. However, it still requires a lot of memory and time, so this approach is not very scalable. I wondered whether there is a more straightforward mathematical technique, before trying to squeeze out maximum efficiency out of the computational approach.

Comment: bitor and the powers of two give a solution.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I am not sure whether I understand you correctly. I don't start with powers of 2 as building blocks, and I also can't construct powers of 2 first and then use them to construct the number in question, because the order of evaluation doesn't allow to simulate arbitrary parentheses.

Comment: okay, why not think about how bitor preserves parity, of one of it's inputs, and how bitand gives back odd values if both inputs are odd